# HTTP Request using Google API Client Library for C++

Tags: c++, http, google-api, google-api-client

I am trying to send an HTTP GET Request using Google API Client Library for C++ using the use case examples mentioned at http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/guide/making_http_requests.html.

Here's my program:

```
#include "googleapis/client/data/data_reader.h"
#include "googleapis/client/transport/http_request.h"
#include "googleapis/client/transport/http_response.h"
#include "googleapis/client/transport/http_transport.h"
#include "googleapis/client/transport/curl_http_transport.h"
#include "googleapis/base/scoped_ptr.h"
#include "googleapis/base/mutex.h"
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include "googleapis/util/status.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace googleapis;
using namespace std;

using googleapis::client::HttpRequest;
using googleapis::client::HttpRequestState;
using googleapis::client::HttpResponse;
using googleapis::client::HttpTransport;
using googleapis::client::HttpTransportLayerConf;
using googleapis::client::HttpTransportOptions;

void IllustrateGet(const char* url, HttpTransport* transport) {
    scoped_ptr<HttpRequest> request(
            transport->NewHttpRequest(HttpRequest::GET));
    request->set_url(url);
    util::Status status = request->Execute();
    if (!status.ok())
        cerr << status.error_message();
}


int main(){

    string url = "http://www.google.com/cloudprint";
    scoped_ptr<HttpTransport> transport;

    IllustrateGet(url, transport);
    return 0;

}
```

In main(), when I try to invoke the IllustrateGet function, I get an invalid argument exception. Could some one help me understand what does HttpTransport do in order to send an HTTP GET Request?

Comment: Do you know how do I change your snippet of code to work without the scoped_ptr ? I downloaded the library now and I can't find a way to include the relevant file for it, i.e.-  googleapis/base/scoped_ptr.h"

Answer (score 1):

Call IllustrateGet(url.c_str(), transport);